# RH Linux Bash Script help. Need to move files with specific words in the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I have a RedHat linux box and I had written a script in the past to move files from one location to another with a specific text in the body of the file.

I typically only write scripts once a year so every year I forget more and more... That being said,

Last year I wrote this script and used it and it worked.

For some reason, I can not get it to work today and I know it's a simple issue and I shouldn't even be asking for help but for some reason I'm just not looking at it correctly today.

Here is the script.

```
ls -1 /var/text.old | while read file
do
grep -q "to.move" $file && mv $file /var/text.old/TBD
done
```

I'm listing all the files inside the /var/text.old directory.
I'm reading each file
then I'm grep'ing for "to.move" and holing the results
then I'm moving the resulting found files to the folder /var/text.old/TBD

I am an admin and I have rights to the above files and folders.
I can see the data in each file
I can mv them manually
I have use pwd to grab the correct spelling of the directory.

If anyone can just help me to see what the heck I'm missing here that would really make my day.

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

The files I need to move do not have Whitespaces.

The Error I'm getting is as follows:

grep: 9829563.msg: No such file or directory

NOTE: the file "982953.msg" is one of the files I need to move.
Also note: I'm getting this error for every file in the directory that I'm listing.

Comment: what kind of error message are you receiving?

Comment: I apologize for that... I do not have any whitespace. there error is as follows. (in next comment.)

Comment: grep: 9829563.msg: No such file or directory

Comment: 9829563.msg is one of the text files I would like to search and then move.

Comment: `for file in /var/text.old/*; do grep -Fq "to.move" "$file" && mv "$file" /var/text.old/TBD/; done`

Comment: anubhava... Can you post your response as an answer so I can mark it "answered"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any error, but I'm gonna take a guess and say that you have a filename with a space or special shell character.

Let's say you have 3 files, and `ls -1` gives us:

```
hello
world
hey there
```

Now, `while` splits on the value of the special `$IFS` variable, which is set to `<space><tab><newline>` by default.
So instead of looping of 3 values like you expect (`hello`, `world`, and `hey there`), you loop over *4* values (`hello`, `world`, `hey`, and `there`).

To fix this, we can do 2 things:

1. Set `IFS` to only a newline:

   ```
   IFS="
   "
   ls -1 /var/text.old | while read file
   ...
   ```

   In general, I like setting `IFS` to a newline at the start of the script, since I consider this to be slightly "safer", but opinions on this probably vary.
2. But much better is to not parse the output of  `ls`, and use `for`:

   ```
   for file in /var/text.old/*`; do
   ```

   This won't fork any external processes (piping to `ls` to `while` starts 2), and behaves "less surprising" in other ways. [See here for some examples](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128987/33645).

---

The second problem is that you're not quoting `$file`. You should always quote pathnames with double quoted: `"$file"` for the same reasons. If `$file` has a space (or a special shell character, such as `*`, the meaning of your command changes:

```
file=hey\ *
mv $file /var/text.old/TBD
```

Becomes:

```
mv hey * /var/text.old/TBD
```

Which is obviously *very* different from what you intended! What you intended was:

```
mv "hey *" /var/text.old/TBD
```